# How to check if a Django CharField is empty

Tags: django, django-models

I've been working on a Django database project and I need to return a value only if a CharField is not empty.

```
class author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Article author')
    pronouns = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Enter pronouns (optional)', blank=True, verbose_name='Pronouns (optional)')
    
    if pronouns != '':
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name} ({self.pronouns})'
    else:
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Despite me not entering anything in the pronouns field when testing, it still acts as if it has a value and returns `Name ()` with nothing in those parentheses.

I have tried, checking if it is `None` or `''` and setting `default=''` and then checking if it is not equal to the default. None of those have worked. How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot define the method of a `class` within `if-else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that `pronouns` will **never** be `''` because it is a model field.  If you `print(pronouns)` when starting the server you will get: `<django.db.models.fields.CharField>`, *not* the pronouns of a specific author.  The solution is very simple though:

```py
class author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Article author')
    pronouns = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='Enter pronouns (optional)', blank=True, verbose_name='Pronouns (optional)')

    def __str__(self):
        if self.pronouns != '':
            return f'{self.name} ({self.pronouns})'
        else:
            return self.name
```

When you do this you using `self` you are accessing the field values of the specific instance of `author`.

Suggestion: Class names should be capitalized:  `class Author` as opposed to `class author`.